# Git pull with mutliple branches - merge with wrong branch

Tags: git, git-pull

My setup is:

```
$ git remote show origin
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: ssh://repo.xxx/project.git
  Push  URL: ssh://repo.xxx/project.git
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    test  tracked
    test2 tracked
  Local refs configured for 'git push':
    test  pushes to test  (up to date)
    test2 pushes to test2 (up to date)
```

I'm on the branch test2 and I add a new file, commit it and push.
Now I checkout the 'test' branch and issue a git pull:

```
touch file.txt
git add file.txt
git commit -m "file.txt"
git push

Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (2/2), 241 bytes, done.
Total 2 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://repo.xxx/project.git
   98dd105..fbbd238  test2 -> test2

git checkout test
git pull
```

And suddenly the content of 'test2' branch gets merged into my current 'test' branch.

What is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for 'git pull --help' describes how the remote branch to merge is determined:

> The rule to determine which remote branch to merge after fetching is a bit involved, in order not to
>          break backward compatibility.

```
   If explicit refspecs were given on the command line of git pull, they are all merged.

   When no refspec was given on the command line, then git pull uses the refspec from the configuration
   or $GIT_DIR/remotes/<origin>. In such cases, the following rules apply:

    1. If branch.<name>.merge configuration for the current branch <name> exists, that is the name of
       the branch at the remote site that is merged.

    2. If the refspec is a globbing one, nothing is merged.

    3. Otherwise the remote branch of the first refspec is merged.
```

From what you described, case 1 doesn't appear to apply because if it did then 'git remote show ...' would have listed branches under a "Local branch configured for 'git pull':" line.  So case 3 must be matching 'origin/test2' when you are on branch 'test'.

Of course, you can avoid the problem by being explicit about the mapping between local and remote branches.  Use:

```
$ git branch --set-upstream test origin/test
$ <similar for test2>
```

Comment: --set-upstream is exactly what was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`git pull` is equivalent to running `git fetch & git merge` you don't pass any arguments to it so it connects to origin and gets two branches merges it into your current branch.

You can either use `git fetch & git merge origin/test1` while on local test1 branch or you can do `git pull origin test1`. I prefer the first one because I can see whats changed on remote while fetching.

Comment: Does the content of FETCH_HEAD has anything to do with that? There are 'not-for-merge' markers in there.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean but FETCH_HEAD is just there for implementation of git pull as it runs `git fetch` and then `git merge FETCH_HEAD`

Comment: There are two branches listed there (test and test2) and test has a not-for-merge option added.

Comment: Although it may seem to be easier to just use `git pull` `git fetch & git merge origin/branch` is much better. Anyways you asked what not-for-merge is FETCH_HEAD is a file that associates sha1's with branches and lines in the file describe the commits that need to be merged into the current HEAD by marking lines with not-for-merge markers. So if your HEAD is in the test1 branch it checks if it needs to merge test2 needs to be merged because its not at HEAD